# My cactus is suddenly becoming white and shrinking

Tags: cactus

Can anyone suggest what could be the problem. I am keeping this in under a shed and watering when the top of the soil is dry. Is it [image]a bug or rot root problem ?
! [image]

Comment: It almost looks like frost or sun damage. Possibly something chemical? Is it only on this side of the plant or all around?

Comment: it is only on one side. It is still in the same condition, rest of the side looks fine.